# Why is Eclipse (Kepler) struggling with HTML5?

Tags: eclipse, html

I just started using Eclipse for work and for whatever reason, it's really wigging out with the HTML I'm writing.

I have WPT installed, and I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The file type is html.

Notice how it's throwing errors at my HTML5 tags

![enter image description here][1]

Any ideas on what might be happening? Or on how I might dig a little deeper into the issue?

Comment: You don't appear to have a close " on the `class="standard-header` which is messing up the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find everything I needed here:

http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/419

Thanks, all.